# can I run a taffydb query ignoring case without combining it with like

Tags: jquery, taffydb

I want to run a case insensitive query using TAFFYDB (upper/lower case).
It appears that likenocase combines "like" with "no case".
In other words, if I'm querying for "bm", I want *BM,bm, Bm, bM*.
What I get, is all those plus anything with bm in it, line *DNA_BM*.

Is there a way to query out of taffy for ONLY case, without combining it with LIKE?

```
  var q=$("#clientID").val();        
  var ret=clientTechs({"clientID":{likenocase:q}}).get();
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shawnsBrain66/evqb4ufL/59/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs (http://taffydb.com/writing_queries.html)

**leftnocase**
Used to see if the start of a column is the same as a supplied value. Ignores case of column and value.

**isnocase**
Used to see if a column value is equal to a supplied value. Ignores case of column and value.

Comment: I must have missed those. They both seem to give me the intended result in my jsfiddle example, though I don't understand completely the difference in the two. I will experiment some more. Thanks!

Comment: Leftnocase checks that the target string starts with the search string . Isnocase checks that the target string equals the search string.